# IFS=$'\n' doesn't change IFS to breaklines

Tags: shell

I wrote the next test shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=$'\n'
for d in `find . -name *.cue -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 dirname | sort --unique`
do
  unset IFS
  echo "$d"
  IFS=$'\n'
done
unset IFS
```

If I execute the find command of the condition in the bash I obtain something like this:

```
./[FLAC] Destination Goa - The Sixth Chapter (CD)/CD2
./[FLAC] Eat Static - Implant - (CD)
./[FLAC] Elysium - Dance For The Celestial Beings (CD)
./[FLAC] Elysium - Monzoon 1996 (CD)
./[FLAC] Etnica - The Juggeling Alchemists Under The Black Light
```

(the name of the folders containing cue files)

In the shell script I want to loop using each one of this folders but, of course, if I don't redefine the IFS the occurreances breaks with spaces:

```
Experience
4
./[FLAC]
VA
-
Trancentral
Five
A
Sonic
Initiation
./[FLAC]
VA
-
Trancentral
```

In other computer (a MacOS) I solved this problem changing the IFS to breaklines with this command `IFS=$'\n'` but in my home computer (an Ubuntu Linux) the loop breaks occurrences with "n":

```
tra
ce - A Trip To Psychedelic Tra
ce (CD)/CD1
./[FLAC] VA - Ta
tra
ce - A Trip To Psychedelic Tra
ce (CD)/CD2
./[FLAC] VA - Tech
o Tra
ce Ma
```

Do you know what's happening and why the different behaviour between computers?
Thank you.

Comment: What does `/bin/sh --version` (or `/bin/sh -v` if that doesn't work) print on both machines?

Comment: This isn't the right way to iterate over lines anyhow. If you had a file with a `*` or other wildcard character in its name, it would be expanded by the shell to to any matching names. The while-loop approach given by @l0b0 is much safer.

Comment: ...and even then, you can't safely delimit filenames using newlines, because filenames *can contain* newlines. What if you had a file named `./$'\n'/etc/passwd$'\n'/foo.cue`? The only safe way to delimit between filenames is with NUL bytes.

Comment: @l0b0, the commands didn't work probably because I was in POSIX shell, not bash. That was the problem. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I want to use find becuase I don't know how deep the files are (but I read that there are better methods), and in my case I know that the files doesn't contain newlines in its name, but I understand your point. Thank you.

Comment: @davidgnin, you can use find without changing IFS, and without it being unsafe. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind, particularly section 5 and below.

Comment: Note that even setting IFS to a newline correctly doesn't make your result strings safe from glob expansion when you do the `for file in $(find ...)` thing. This is also described in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set IFS to to a newline like this:

```
IFS="
"
```

`$'\n'` is ksh93/bash/zsh syntax but it is not POSIX syntax. On most current systems `#!/bin/sh` points to a POSIX shell (although this is not demanded by POSIX and Solaris 9,10 is an exception).

Whether that shell happens to understand `$'\n'` is not something you should rely on. If you want to use `$'\n'` change you shebang to `#!/bin/bash` or one of the other shells..

---

On Ubuntu and debian linux and derivatives `/bin/sh` points to `dash` . With some other distributions it points to `/bin/bash --posix` (bash in posix mode)...

---

Another point to note is that if you unset IFS you are not returning to the previous state, which is IFS that contains a space, a TAB and a newline. By unsetting IFS , field splitting will be done as if IFS contains a space, a TAB and a newline, so all seems well.

Unsetting IFS can give complications, however, if this is mixed with the regular practice

```
  unset IFS        # Unset the IFS variable so it does not exist
  oldIFS=$IFS      # The old state is supposedly saved
  IFS=:            # IFS is set to some string
  IFS=$oldIFS      # Now IFS is set to the empty string, which means no field 
                   # splitting is performed at all
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves everything. I didn't know that the shell wasn't bash.

Comment: Applied these suggestions in Ubuntu 14.04, with GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). The first serving is the one it works in default conditions. To have the writing `IFS=$'\n'` working, I type it within a shell session started with `bash --posix'. These suggestions clarify tens of other posts all over Stackoverflow on the theme word splitting and IFS in bash

Comment: Yep, `IFS=$'\n'` is a bashism (+ other shells, use [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html), your way is more portable.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the loop at all. This should do what you want:

```
find . -name *.cue -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 dirname | sort --unique
```

If you really want to loop over the results, [you should use `while` rather than `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < "$file"
```

or

```
my_script | while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```

Going back to the question about splitting on a literal `n` character, it could be that `/bin/sh` on your Ubuntu machine doesn't support the [`$''` bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism#Syntax).

Comment: There are better ways to do the dirname, too, with a find having `-printf` (which has a format operator to emit dirname directly).

Comment: ...and doing that, you can have the input to `sort` being NUL-delimited, so you could use `sort -z` (or whatever the GNU extension for that is), and the safer `while IFS= read -r -d '' line`.

Comment: The body of the loop was an example. I don't want to just print the lines, sorry for the bad explanation. Thank you for the info about for and while.