# create file from existing file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file in `Liunx` that has so many lines.

`Contents of the file:`

```
abcdeqroop[
g
;ld

'
d
sksd
;
s'sa;abcdeqroop';kaf
100 gmail eng en101 usa ten
yahoomail dffdd
''

100 200 hotmail and'usfifoi2[[[[[10101
f[
dsl
ks

s'dakd
sd1jz
sdj
sasa;kas

';cxvdl;s;4

;sdljodsl

600 outlookmail 79903083434==13==
```

From this file I want to create a new file like below

```
gmail eng en101 usa ten
yahoomail dffdd
hotmail and'usfifoi2[[[[[10101
outlookmail 79903083434==13==
```

`Conditions to create the file.`

check if any line has following strings present `gmail, yahoomail, hotmail, outlookmail`.

```
If string is not present then delete the file.
If string is present then delete all the characters before it and get the rest of the characters as new line.
```

How can I do that?

I have done like below

```
grep -E 'gmail|yahoomail|outlookmail|hotmail' test_file
```

The output I got is below

```
100 gmail eng en101 usa ten
yahoomail dffdd
100 200 hotmail and'usfifoi2[[[[[10101
600 outlookmail 79903083434==13==
```

Comment: Using bash for first condition use grep (you can use grep with multiple keywords, and remove file if they are doesn't exist), for second one sed should be enough. This could help a little: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541867/sed-delete-lines-not-containing-specific-string

Comment: @darvark Please check updated part of my question with what I tried

Comment: Use grep with -L option, and check return status, if words exists then return code is 0, in other case 127

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: you're almost there. Look at piping your `grep -E` output to `sed` and using sed feature "capture groups" See the [sed tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a small script for it, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
echo -n "Choose the file to read: "; read File
echo -n "Name of the file to be saved: "; read File2
true > $File2

for line in `cat $File`
do
    case "$line" in
    *"hotmail"*) echo -e $line | sed 's/^.*hotmail/hotmail/'  >> $File2;;
    *"yahoo"*) echo -e $line | sed 's/^.*yahoo/yahoo/'  >> $File2;;
    *"gmail"*) echo -e $line | sed 's/^.*gmail/gmail/'  >> $File2;;
    *"outlookmail"*) echo -e $line | sed 's/^.*outlookmail/outlookmail/'  >> $File2;;
    esac

done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

I hope this is for you some help

Comment: For the handling of IFS, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23032752/5459638. This is useful if you don't manage to get Linux concatenating the words in one string

Answer (score -1):

You can use below commands -

First part - To find mail alias from whole file

```
egrep -r "*mail*" temp >> temp1
```

Second part - To remove extra characters

```
sed -re "s@(.*)\s(.*mail)(.*)@\2\3@" temp1
```